# Overhead of `using`

Tags: c++, optimization, type-alias

For my problem, I can use the `using` directive in two ways. They basically boil down to these options:

```
template<typename U>
struct A {
private:

    // Define our types
    using WrapperType = Wrapper<U>;

public:

    U *operator()(U *g) const {
       // TODO: use WrapperType 
    }
};
```

OR:

```
struct B {

    template <typename U>   
    U *operator()(U *g) const {

       // Define the types here instead.
       using WrapperType = Wrapper<U>;

       // TODO: use WrapperType 
    }
};
```

In both cases, there will be other class template parameters. So `B` will still have template parameters, even though it doesn't look like it in this simplified example.

My question is:

*Is there any overhead of defining a type locally like in `B`? (when compared to `A`)?*

It isn't clear to me how the type declaration affects the generated code. The code must run in real time, and this will be the core of the codebase. So if there is any overhead whatsoever, I cannot use `B`.

That being said, `B` IS preferable in our case, because I would ideally like to call this code with a variety of types. And yes, this really does need to be in a class. I have just simplified the example extremely.

Comment: All you are doing is defining a type alias - unless I'm missing something that should not have any effect on runtime performance?

Comment: That is exactly what I am wondering.

Comment: I am concerned that the `using` directive might be doing something like redefining a type each time the `()` operator is called.

Comment: Are you using some sort of interpreted C++ implementation? Or compiling to some target machine code?

Comment: The difference is in scope of the type alias - in the second case, it cannot be used in other member functions of `B` unless they also do the same.   From a maintenance perspective, it's a trade-off  i.e. which is better depends on the overall structure of your code.

Comment: Compiling to code

Comment: Typedefs are just information for the compiler, they do not affect the generated code. You just need to be careful that you do not accidentally use another type after adding / moving a typedef.

Comment: They really are only used in the one function. But they are necessary for readability because the template parameters are > 100 characters long, and repeated several times

Comment: So without them, the code would just look like a mess

Comment: @StoryTeller I didn't thought of that possibility. Even though it is not OP's case, I think it deserves an answer (ping me, will upvote (even though I'm sure you've already reached the 200 cap)).

Comment: @YSC - That's too nitpicky even for me :) I just wanted to assure the OP it's unlikely

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Is there any overhead [on the generated code] of defining a type locally like in B?

No there isn't any.

Defining a type alias (what you do with `using WrapperType = Wrapper<U>;`) only affects compilation and is completely removed once run-time begins.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to hear... I thought that this was the answer, but I just wanted to make sure.